# Table view custom cell not responding according to constraints

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, swift2, nslayoutconstraint

I am designing a table view in which I have a custom cell in which I am trying to design a few views and sub views. I have placed my views as per the following hierarchy and constraints -

[image]

And here is my main story board -

[image]

I have given my table view cell's content view as orange colour and I have placed a view with yellow colour. I have pinged it to the content view of the cell. My storyboard is of the size 600*600 freeform(Size class - wAny hAny). When I run my app in ipad, it keeps a space as shown below between the cell's content view and its subview even on pinning the subview to all sides of content view-

[image]

So,what might be my problem and what mistake am I making? Thanks.

Comment: Hi @G.Abhisek. my first guess is the prolem coming from the sizing classes. What do you mean by "My storyboard is of the size 600*600"

Comment: @Ismail I used the size because in any freeform size of main story board I design my app I get the subview of that size. So never worry that is the default screen size when you open XCode. As you can see the spacing in my simulator. And if I design the same screen in a 4 inch screen it would leave back much spacing .

Comment: I also implement with same Layout constraint and facing same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is because of the `sizing classes` (like in the image).
if your app is **universal** (for both **iPhone** and **iPad**) make sure you choose it like the screenshot **(w Any, h Any)**. 
 [image]

Please let me know the current settings.

**Update**
After sending me the storyboard. I have used it as it is in a new project. and that's how it looks in both **iPhone** and **iPad**[image: iPhone]
[image: iPade]

- It looks fine in both of them. my best guess is it's a problem of the
  preview only(which doesn't matter).
- If you change the scene size from **iPhone 4 inch** to **inferred**
  it solve the problem in the preview as well.

Comment: I had the size classes as wAny hAny.

Comment: @G.Abhisek Could you please upload this storyboard file (or repreduce the same issue in a new one). and send the the URL so I can give you a better help?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/dhk5rrme1j2g89g/Main.storyboard?dl=0 . check this link. Kindly please check the preview,you can get exactly what I am asking.

Comment: @G.Abhisek Please see my upated answer. Please let me know if you had any issue with running.or any other questions.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I have also tried the same stuff in a normal default storyboard of XCode i.e 600*600 but still it shows the same in preview but runs okay in simulator. So what might be the issue? Thanks again for your helpful response.

Comment: @G.Abhisek I see, It shows the same issue in the preview sometimes. My suggestion is to just ignore it, it might be a bug in the preview, but it has no effect on your app.

Comment: Ya I also tried by putting many constraints other than this but, it only shows a gap in preview but no where else. Thanks for your response again.